# Room Query BETWEEN dates doesnt return result

Tags: android, sqlite, sorting, android-room

I am working on an application where i practice working with Room Persistence Library.
I have a class called expence based on which is the database with fields int amount and Date dob and other.
My goal is to use query below to return the sum of all entries between these dates.

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM expence WHERE dob BETWEEN date( :start ) AND   date( :end )     ")
    int  newallexpensesFromTo(String start,String end);//
```

But at the curent state the query doesnt return anything and the textview i want to display the result  = 0;

I have used guidance from http://androidkt.com/datetime-datatype-sqlite-using-room/  - to be able to convert from strings to Date and revese.

I have checked maybe its due to different format of the stored date and its the same the one stored in database and the one passed to query.

This is where i try to get the sum of the entries

```
value2 =db.expenceDao().newallexpensesFromTo(firstdayofmonth,lastdayofmonth);
```

I have a similar query where without the dates and it returns all entries.
When i add an expense i use DatePicker to add the Date to the dob in database.

Expected result is to receive the sum of entries added between these dates when the query receives the strings with the dates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try converting and inserting your `startDate` and `endDate` as a long timestamp value into your `expense` table instead of storing it in some another format.

Now while querying the data, use the timestamp values of your query dates.

For e.g., if you want `SUM(amount)` between `01-05-2019` and `31-05-2019` than your query would be like:

```
@Query("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM expense WHERE dob BETWEEN :startDate AND :endDate")
int  newAllExpensesFromTo(Long startDate,Long endDate);
```

Where your `startDate` and `endDate` values will be something like `1556668800` & `1559260800` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

For now you can use [**type converters**](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/referencing-data).

As described in docs for `Date` your converter in Java should looks like below

```java
public class Converters {
    @TypeConverter
    public static Date fromTimestamp(Long value) {
        return value == null ? null : new Date(value);
    }

    @TypeConverter
    public static Long dateToTimestamp(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.getTime();
    }
}
```

To apply them, add below code above the class inheriting from `RoomDatabase()`

```java
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
```

Finally you will be able to use it like that

```java
@Query("SELECT SUM(amount) FROM expence WHERE dob BETWEEN :from AND :to")
int newallexpensesFromTo(from: Date, to: Date)
```